# Why is the month of Aadi considered auspicious for the Goddess Parvati (Ambaal)?

Tags: belief, rituals, goddess

The month of Aadi in the [Tamil calendar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamil_calendar) is considered particularly auspicious for the Goddess Parvati, i.e. Ambaal.

Why is this so?

(In case it matters, my perspective comes from that of a Tamil Brahmin household.)

Possibly relevant: I know that there are several local/rural dieties of South India such as [Mariamman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mariamman) for whom there are festivals celebrated in the month of Aadi, and Mariamman is considered to be another form of Ambaal.

Comment: Its hard to answer why... for example why is Friday for devi or why specific month like shraavan for Shiva in northern India

Comment: @RakeshJoshi I don't disagree that it may be hard to answer why. :) But, I hope that that's not a criticism of the question itself?